# Neo4j Browser Cypher Query Results Movement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4J browswer, when you want to visualize some data, a nice interface is available for Cypher queries. The trouble is the nodes are continuously moving around, and usually 90% of them are off screen. Surprisingly I cant find much info on the purpose of this. is there a way to stop this annoying movement?

Comment: Using the LIMIT keyword to load only a visible snip of your data ? Or put some additional RAM to your computer ;)

Comment: What kind of query do you execute?

Comment: It usually settles after a few seconds and you can drag it around. There is also a fullscreen option.

Comment: Also you can click/drag on the white background to move the viewport

Comment: Perhaps in future versions there will be the ability to pan around? i do like the prettifying rendering, just would be nice to always have it on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible 'easily' turn off shaking of the nodes in the Neo4j web console.